# Attribute Not Changing in DB

Tags: mysql, ruby-on-rails

I am trying to change an attribute for contract, allowing the user to "approve" or "reject"

```
  <%= link_to_unless_current("Approve", { decision: "approve" }) %>
  <%= link_to_unless_current("Reject", { decision: "reject" }) %>
```

I am not getting any errors but the change is not showing up in my database.  In my rails console, it seem like the action is being pass through.  I've also added :status to my strong params in my contracts controller.

Here is my controller snippet

```
 def evaluate
    if params[:decision] == "approve"
      @contract.status = "approve"
    else params[:decision] == "reject"
      @contract.status = "reject"
    end
    @contract.save
  end
```

And my controller params

```
  def contract_params
      params.require(:contract).permit(:price, :start_date, :end_date, :open_ended, :lessor_contact_name, :lessor_business_name, :lessee_name, :lessee_email, :lessee_address, :lessee_business_name, :lessee_guarantor, :status)
    end
```

And here is my rails console.  You'll see that the contract is being "approved". . . it's just not saving to the db.

```
Started GET "/spaces/1/contracts/17?decision=approve" for ::1 at 2015-08-07 09:23:27 -0400
  ActiveRecord::SchemaMigration Load (0.1ms)  SELECT "schema_migrations".* FROM "schema_migrations"
Processing by ContractsController#show as HTML
  Parameters: {"decision"=>"approve", "space_id"=>"1", "id"=>"17"}
  User Load (0.3ms)  SELECT  "users".* FROM "users" WHERE "users"."id" = ?  ORDER BY "users"."id" ASC LIMIT 1  [["id", 2]]
  Space Load (0.1ms)  SELECT  "spaces".* FROM "spaces" WHERE "spaces"."id" = ? LIMIT 1  [["id", 1]]
  Property Load (0.1ms)  SELECT  "properties".* FROM "properties" WHERE "properties"."id" = ? LIMIT 1  [["id", 1]]
  Contract Load (0.2ms)  SELECT  "contracts".* FROM "contracts" WHERE "contracts"."id" = ? LIMIT 1  [["id", 17]]
  User Load (0.2ms)  SELECT  "users".* FROM "users" WHERE "users"."id" = ? LIMIT 1  [["id", 2]]
  Rendered contracts/_landlord.html.erb (6.5ms)
  Rendered contracts/show.html.erb within layouts/application (11.6ms)
  Rendered layouts/_header.html.erb (0.8ms)
Completed 200 OK in 563ms (Views: 494.5ms | ActiveRecord: 2.1ms)
```

And here are my routes

```
  resources :spaces do
    collection do
      get 'search'
    end
    resources :galleries do
      resources :pictures
    end
    resources :contracts do
      post 'evaluate', on: :member
    end
    resources :reviews
  end
```

Any help is great.  Thanks

Comment: Are you missing a contract.save?

Comment: @DavidK-J, yes I am saving the contract.  I revised my question.  still the db is not changing though

Answer (score 0):

Firstly, it looks like you misspelled the parameter name. Change it to this:

```
<%= link_to_unless_current("Approve", { decision: "approve" }) %>
<%= link_to_unless_current("Reject", { decision: "reject" }) %>
```

...because you use `params[:decision]` in your controller, not `params[:evaluate]`.

Secondly, I'm not very sure that `decision` (or `evaluate`) parameter would present in your initial request to the Rails, when you render this view. Just to make things certain, use regular `if` operator instead:

```
<% decision = {'approve' => 'reject', 'reject' => 'approve'}[@contract.status] %>
<%= link_to("Approve", url_for(decision: decision)) %>
```

Finally, you have wrong URL for your link. That's the right one:

```
<%= link_to("Approve", url_for(action: 'evaluate', decision: decision), method: :post) %>
```

Comment: @zkidd I don't see an updated in params. Please add that to your question if you fixed that.

Comment: also, please add your `routes.rb` – there seems to be a problem with routing, you might want to make a POST request instead of GET

Comment: @zkidd You have wrong URL of your form. Please add how do you write `form_for` tag to your question. Ah, wait, you don't write form_for at all! Wait a second, I will update my answer.

Comment: @zkidd I've updated my answer. Add `url_for(action: 'evaluate', decision: '...), method: 'post'` to your link.

Comment: I am trying to use this process (http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActionView/Helpers/UrlHelper.html#method-i-link_to)  the link_to_unless_current pattern

Comment: `link_to_unless_current` checks whether current page equals the page it leads to. But you need to get user to **completely another action** (page). You are placing link on `contacts/show` action, and you lead user to `contacts/evaluate` action. How do you suppose to use that pattern in such case? :)

Comment: I'm not trying to lead the user to a new page.  I just want the user to be able to approve or reject a contract's status and for the contract status to change in the db.  But the user should not be redirected anywhere.

Comment: What `link_to_unless_current` has to do with that, exactly?

Answer (score 0):

The problem you are having is directly related to the way that rails updates and saves data in the database. In your `evaluate` method you are setting the value of `status` to approve or reject, but simply setting the value doesn't actually **save** the value. So, you can do one of two things.

1) In your `evaluate` method you can save the record after setting it:

```
def evaluate
  if params[:decision] == "approve"
    @contract.status = "approve"
  else params[:decision] == "reject"
    @contract.status = "reject"
  end
  @contract.save
end
```

2) Or you can use the `update_attributes` which automatically saves it for you:

```
def evaluate
  if params[:decision] == "approve"
    @contract.update_attributes(status: "approve")
  else params[:decision] == "reject"
    @contract.update_attributes(status: "reject")
  end
end
```

Try that out and see how it goes.

Comment: Here's my rails console: 

Started GET "/spaces/1/contracts/17?decision=reject" for ::1 at 2015-08-06 19:26:00 -0400
  ActiveRecord::SchemaMigration Load (0.1ms)  SELECT "schema_migrations".* FROM "schema_migrations"
Processing by ContractsController#show as HTML
  Parameters: {"decision"=>"reject", "space_id"=>"1", "id"=>"17"}....